# Loading Data without pausing the activity in fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, progressdialog

i have an app that extends view pager. Every single tab of the view pager get filled from online database, however i have a tiny problem in loading :-)

I use Asynctask when the activity first start but that really spoil the user experience as i want it to be more smooth and interactive.
So after looking to the new updated zedge app, i want to do the exact same thing to my fragments.

This image explains everything :

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ryCVc.png

Their loading is smooth and i want mine to be too, so how can i do it?

**Basically**: i want the progress dialog to be inside the fragment and be gone when the loading is finished. I know we know i can do it by modifying visibility, but how can i load the data from my online database to the offline database while the user can still swipe between tabs.

Comment: what do you mean by 'it spoil the user experience'? what do you mean by smooth?

Comment: i mean i want the loading to be inside the fragment, like the dialog is in the screenshot and yet i dont want the loading to pause the activity, as the user can swipe between tabs while it's loading

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be about what you want...

```
class AsyncGet extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void>
        {

        private ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(getSherlockActivity());

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPreExecute();
            progressDialog.setMessage("Getting Information...");
            progressDialog.show();
            progressDialog.setOnCancelListener(new OnCancelListener() {
        @Override
            public void onCancel(DialogInterface arg0) {
            AsyncGet.this.cancel(true);
        }
           });

        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            //your stuff here
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPostExecute(result);
progressDialog.dismiss();
//Update UI
}
}
```

Comment: do i do that inside the fragment?? i dont want the progress dialog to display a message and i dont want it to be a dialog, just a turning wheel.

Comment: yes you do that inside a fragment it will work...for the turning wheel you can make it appear in the onPreExecute(). First give your parent view an id in your layout. set its visibility to GONE. and make the wheel visible by introducing it programatically and in the onPostExecute() when you have fetched your data make the wheel invisivle and change your parent layout's visiblity to VISIBLE.

Comment: for you to preload stuff i guess you can fire an intent service to preload data from webservice into a SQLite db it will do all its work in the background. and later read from the whenever the user swipes on to the appropriate tab!

Answer (score 0):

try this in xml file

```
 <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:visibility="visible" >

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/loading_time_progress_bar"
            android:layout_width="20dip"
            android:layout_height="20dip"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: ok then how i load the data from the online database without pausing the activity???

Comment: put `invisible` to your progress bar in your xml file,like this `android:visibility="invisible"` and after that your `onPreExecute()` call visible function like    `ProgressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);` in `onPostExecute()` call like this invisible `ProgressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);`

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by adding a **progressbar** inside **every fragment layout**. Make this progressbar "**visible**" and all other layout "**gone**"  untill you load all the data of your UI .Do it for each individual fragment. When data loading is done make your UI **visible** .In this way it will not stop navigation because it is not progress dialog, it is a progressbar inside a layout.

Hope it will help.

Comment: my problem is: how can i load the data without pausing the activity. if i do it in async task the user wont be able to swipe between tabs and the dialog fragments inside the view pager will be useless